# changing dropdown values in ORO commerce

Tags: orocommerce, orocrm

I would like to change the select dropdown on the list of products with the number of displayed items per page. By default, it's set to 10, 25, 50, and 100. I want to replace these values with 5, 10, 20, 30. How can I do that?

I tried to override some js files but with no result.

Answer (score 1):

You can override it per grid in the yaml configuration:

```
datagrids:
    <grid-name>:
        options:
            toolbarOptions:
                pageSize:
                    items: [10, 20, 30]
                    default_per_page: 10
```